# python subprocess callback when updated output

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, subprocess, tornado

I am using tornado. I hope the following is easy to understand, It's spawning a tcproute process and sending the output to the websocket's other end.

```
class TracerouteHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  def open(self,ip):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['traceroute',ip],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while p.poll() is None: #running
      line=p.stdout.readline()
      if line!=None and len(line)>0:
        self.write_message(json.dumps({'stdout':line})) 
    self.write_message(json.dumps({'stdout':'Done! For red marked ip addresses, the location couldn\'t be determined with <a href="http://hostip.info">hostip.info</a>. If you know the correct location, please update it there.'}))
```

The problem is that due to the `while p.poll() is None` loop, tornado blocks. Also, if there's nothing in p.stdout to read, the `p.stdout.readline` blocks. So I'd like to have some sort of callback mechanism that gets fired when I have something new in `p.stdout`. How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/513688

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), a non-blocking messaging mechanism which comes with Python.

There is a really nice implementation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python/4896288#4896288), where a separate Thread reads output line from the process, and writes them to the Queue. The main thread can read from the queue in a non-blocking fashion.

Thanks to [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513688/andrew) for the link in the comment.

Comment: Threads themselves are not very good in Python, so I'd try [toro](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) 's Queue.